# Можно сделать несколько открытых балунов?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть карта, на ней метки.

При наведении на метку необходимо показывать один балун, при клике - другой. Только необходимо не закрывать балун открытый при клике, при ховере на другие метки. Есть возможность такое реализовать?
Если да, то возможно как-то сделать, чтобы балун был всегда снизу справа карты?

Answer (score 1):

можно, с помощью js и css, при наведении делаете видимым балун но когда надимаете то делаете балун-2 видимым, может вообще без js сделать а с помощью checkbox - это ваша метка, если checkbox:cheked то тогда показываем балун тот что на клик, а тот что с ховером будет скрыт и все или с помощью js добавлять/удалять класс при клике